# Get average of TIME(7)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

```
ProcessTime: 00:00:00.0000012
RegexResolveTime: 00:00:00.0000421
MessageResolveTime: 00:00:00.0001269 
FullProcessTime: 00:00:00.0001734
```

Ok, I've got 4 columns as above with datatype `Time(7)`. I need to get the average of all the entries for those individual columns but `Time(7)` isn't a valid type for the `AVG` operator!

How does one go about getting the average of a `Time(7)` column?

I'll add that these are Timespans and not discrete points in time even though SQL server considers them such!

Comment: @JustinPihony I think it's different. That question is about `varchar` storing a time value before `time` was even available, and the accepted answer and several others are not an optimal solution in SQL Server 2008+ IMHO...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't average TIME because TIME represents a point in time, not a duration. I suggest one of two approaches.

1. **The preferred approach**: store duration as an integer in milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, what have you. This will allow you much more precision if needed.
2. Apply conversions back and forth so you can average the delta from midnight instead of the actual time value.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (ProcessTime TIME(7));

INSERT @x VALUES ('00:00:00.0000012'), ('00:00:00.0000016');

SELECT DATEADD(NANOSECOND, AVG(DATEDIFF(NANOSECOND, '00:00:00.0000000', ProcessTime)), 
  CONVERT(TIME, '00:00:00.0000000'))
FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
00:00:00.0000014
```

But doesn't that seem wrong to you? If you're not storing a point in time and you're only concerned about duration, store the duration. You can always format it as time when displaying.

Comment: Hi Aaron; they are intervals as it happens; the corresponding upper layer Entity Framework (.NET) data type is a Timespan! So I suppose I need to convert the interval to an integer for AVG purposes; which I think is what you've done there.. I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Perfect.. Gold star for you Aaron

Comment: Intervals are not yet implemented in SQL Server; so when you store it as time, SQL Server sees it and treats it as a point in time. If you want an interval in a future version of SQL Server, please vote and add your business case as a comment to the following Connect item: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432281/sql-server-doesnt-have-an-ansi-interval-data-type